# How to create dynamic testfiles with PHP?

Tags: php, performance, apache, dynamic, download

I want to create a script which gets for example this input "100MB", creates a file with exactly this size and force the client to download it. This is for testing the download speed.

The script I have right now is basicly working, it calculates the actual size in bytes and force the client to download.

The problem right know is, that it runs on an apache webserver so gzip is active and when I only write zeros in the file gzip compress them and I get a downlaod speed which is equal to the writespeed of my hard drive disk. If I create random numbers it gets a lot better but the speed is still to high and the CPU load of the server is way too high.

So I am looking for a solution to get the actual speed and not kill the server.

Edit: The code I have right now:

```
//byteconvert converts the input to bytes...
$size = byteconvert(str_replace("_", "", $_GET['size']));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="testdl.dat"');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
header('Connection: close');

while($size > 1024)
{
    for($i=0; $i<1024; $i+=4) {
        echo(rand(1000, 9999));
    }
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    $size -=1024
}

for($i=0; $i<$size; $i+=1) {
    echo(rand(1, 9));
}
```

Comment: Show the script you have.

Comment: What random do you use. If you are on *nix, you can use `/dev/urandom` for fast random numbers. (12 secs for 100MB, one core busy)

Comment: Another thing you can do is create a large random file upfront and only stream N bytes to the client. No file generation needed in that case.

Comment: I added the source code. Hope that helps.

Comment: @KaRi that first `while` loop never ends if size is larger than 1024. It will never run if it is <= 1024.

Comment: I don't now where I lost the line: $size-=1024; but it is in my code, so that is not the problem.